# How to have smooth animations when using <TransitionGroup> for table rows in tables?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, css-animations

I am trying to use the `<TransitionGroup>` component in Vue3 to animate the insertion and removal of rows in a table according to the documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#move-transitions

However, the example uses `"position: absolute"` when it's animating the removal of an element in the TransitionGroup.

This collapses the layout of the row that is being removed and as a consequence the animation does not look nice. Adding elements to the table works well and looks nice. It is just the removal that is the problem. Ideally, removal would look just like the reverse of adding the rows.

The absolute position comes from the following style from the example:

```
/* ensure leaving items are taken out of layout flow so that moving
   animations can be calculated correctly. */
.list-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here is an example in the Vue3 SFC Playground:
https://play.vuejs.org/#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

I've tried using all the CSS properties that I think could fix this, however, I do not know how to make this work using `<table>` and `<tr>` elements. I might be able to make something that looks like a table while not actually using `<table>` html elements but I'd prefer to continue using tables if possible.

Comment: Can you try removing `.list-leave-active { position: absolute; }` and add `overflow:hidden` in table tag.

Comment: I tried but it seems like the `overflow: hidden` doesn't have any effect.  Then it is basically like the following example: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#enter-leave-transitions. As it says in the docs, this way *"has some obvious flaws: when an item is inserted or removed, its surrounding items instantly "jump" into place instead of moving smoothly."*

Comment: @InvisibleGorilla i'll post a solution tomorrow